# Right Button Problem

Tags: interface

I have been using right click for placing the pivot point on both 2.7 and 2.8. 
I just loaded default settings (2.8) then I get a context menu when I right click on the mesh.

I used to select an edge and right click near it and use my move/rotate/scale tool now I get an object context menu in edit mode. To be honest, I must have gotten over this problem when I started using 2.8 a few months ago. Now I cant fix it.

Comment: Hi. Can you clarify what you mean by "placing the pivot point"? Do you mean placing the 3D cursor or that when you click on an edge the 3D manipulator used to appear?

Comment: Hi. Exactly as you said. 3D Manipulator used to appear. now a menu comes

Comment: [link[(https://i.imgur.com/KZEWeIF.mp4) this is what i dont need